# Formula for Numbering Records

Tags: c#, sql

I have a client that allows users to specify a particular format for records.  Not the id, but as good as.

So the user can select a format of say

- yyyy-1st 3 chrs of client name-next available file number

or

- file manager initials, next file number, yy

or

- next file number, yyyy, file manager initials

they can also add more items so you might get

- next file number-yyyy-client initials-managers initials-yy

Having difficulty visualising the solution on this and how to store the format in a table, pull it out and generate the required number.

Especially given that the client can

- change format at any time
- the next file number needs to be the next one.

I guess the important piece i am missing here is to generate a query giving me the "next file number" if there are already records.

**edit**

not limited to sql.  I just can't think of a solution that will allow me to store a number in a custom format and then generate the next number based on that format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we require our users to do is to reformat the existing records when they change the format. When the format is changed, we know the old format and the new format, so we can update the existing records.

If the visual record number is integral to your operations and needs to be retained, I would then keep a shadow copy in the record that contains the record number formatted according to the current format. You can update this in all records when the format is changed and finding the next available number is now a simple select statement.

Comment: No they can't change the number of existing records, only change the format of any new records.  Sorry, that wasn't very clear

Comment: @griegs: Do the old numbers have to be taken into account when determining the next available number?

Comment: not unless they switch back to a previous format that has records against it no.

Comment: Is there a portion of the number that is always numeric and incrementing regardless what other data is in the number?

Comment: Yes the Next File Number field

Comment: In that case, I think that you need to separate the incrementing file number from the display number. This way, it is easy to get the next file number and then use the format to render the display number when the record is saved

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking but didn't really like the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I dont quite understand what you mean, but this may possible enlighten you more.

This is what I would possible do:

```
typedef struct tagRecord
{
Date (dd/mm/yyyy)
Initials_Client
Initials_FileManager
Next_File_Number
} Record;
...

Let: 
d = Date, ci = Initials_Client, fmi = Initials_FileManager, nfn = Next_File_Number

SelectFormat(record[0], "dci"); // Display Date and Initials_Client

Output: 
12/4/2011 MH

or

SelectFormat(record[0], "cid"); // Initials_Client and Display Date

Output: 
MH 12/4/2011
```

If you need more pseudo-code, please ask.

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm missing something here.  Kinda unsure what you are doing.

Comment: I would have to post some more code for ya. Sorry, I may have got the wrong idea. If you can specify your main points, that might help me understand what your trying to do.